# Not all Paths return a value : C#

Tags: c#

Forgive me if this is basics, I have a following function

```
private ReportOption GetReportOptions(int id, DataRow dr)
{
    string reportType = GetValue(dr, "Report Type");
    if (reportType == "Single")
    {
        GetSingleReportOptions(id, dr);               
    }
    else
    {
        GetMultipleReportOptions(id, dr);
    }
}
```

Now both my functions `GetSingleReportOptions` and `GetMultipleReportOptions` are returning a value of type `ReportOption`.

Still it gives me an error

> Not all code paths return a value

Can you tell me why? How should I structure this function or make change in two helper functions?

Comment: You dont use the word `return` anywhere.

Comment: Use `Return` it should solve the issue

Comment: Technically, NO paths return a value...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `GetReportOptions` doesn't `return` the results of either `GetSingleReportOptions` or `GetMultipleReportOptions`.  It just calls those methods and ignores their return values.  Preface both method calls with `return` so that this method will return the results of those methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are close with what you have. As long as your methods `GetSingleReportOptions` and `GetMultipleReportOptions` Do return a `ReportOption` all you need to do is add return before the method call and you should be good.

```
private ReportOption GetReportOptions(int id, DataRow dr)
{
    string reportType = GetValue(dr, "Report Type");
    if (reportType == "Single")
    {
        return GetSingleReportOptions(id, dr);               
    }
    else
    {
        return GetMultipleReportOptions(id, dr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method has no return statement but a return-type different from void.
Add a return statement at the end of the method

Comment: Your answer doesn't help explain what needs to be returned at the end of the method.